# Are assets lost in a bankruptcy valued at the time of loss, or according to current value?

Tags: taxes, fraud, bankruptcy, capital-loss

For the purposes of claiming a casualty loss in tax filings, can stocks be valued at their current par or is their value only what it was at the time of the loss?

My situation is that I have stock that was held by company that went bankrupt due to fraud. The bankruptcy trustee has valued the loss of the account holders, including myself, according to the value of their holdings *at the time of the bankruptcy*. So in other words, my stock was worth, say, $100,000 at the time of the bankruptcy, so according to the trustee my claim against the company is for that amount.

However, for tax purposes, eventually I will be able to declare a casualty loss because fraud was involved. I will claim this loss when the bankruptcy is settled. So, for example, lets say that in the settlement I get $50,000. Then, *against my creditor claim* I have lost $50,000. However, let's say the value of the stock lost has gone up to $300,000 in the meantime.

Can I claim a $250,000 loss to the IRS, or can I only claim the creditor loss of $50,000?

**More Info**

Note that this question revolves around [Casualty Loss deduction](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc515.html).

> Theft losses are generally deductible in the year you discover the
>   property was stolen unless you have a reasonable prospect of recovery
>   through a claim for reimbursement. In that case, **no deduction is
>   available until the taxable year in which you can determine with
>   reasonable certainty whether or not you'll receive such
>   reimbursement**.

Because of this I cannot estimate the loss until the bankruptcy settles. The IRS guidance says the following:

> The amount of your theft loss is generally the adjusted basis of your
>   property because the fair market value of your property immediately
>   after the theft is considered to be zero.

So, it comes down to how the "adjusted basis" is to be calculated.

**Note:** I did not have stock in the company. They were holding the stock and other assets for me and other clients as a trustee. They STOLE stock and money belonging to their clients. They were apparently planning to later buy it back so noone would ever know, but they went bankrupt before that happened. So me and the other clients essentially have a claim on a bankrupt company. Eventually when the bankruptcy settles, the clients will get back some fraction of their assets. For non-monetary assets (like stock), the bankruptcy trustee  has valued them at their market value at the time of the bankruptcy.

Comment: What is your basis in the original position in the example?  It's part of a minimum test: " the amount of your casualty loss is the lesser of:

The adjusted basis of your property, or
The decrease in fair market value of your property as a result of the casualty"  https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc515.html

Comment: @user662852, you should post that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: I don't know of too many situations in law where you can claim a loss based on what "would have" happened, because they make too many assumptions.  For instance, you're effectively asserting that if not for the fraud, you would have held the stock until the present day.  What if it had gone down to $60,000?  Would you have accepted that you could only claim a loss of $10,000?  Or would you say "no way I would have ridden the stock all the way down, I would have sold at $90,000"?  You can't have it both ways.

Comment: For that matter, why not say: "If not for the fraud, I would have sold the stock and bought XYZ instead, which went up to $2,000,000, so my loss is $1,950,000"? If you go down that road, there's no limit to the shenanigans.

Comment: @quid, it's not an answer, it's eliciting details for the question ;-).  Also, I see on that link there is a special section on "Ponzi-Type Schemes" which I am reading for the first time myself, so I can't claim I'm going to have a complete and correct answer in any case.  Five Bagger, is the underlying fraud a Ponzi-type scheme?

Comment: @user662852 No, it was embezzlement by an insider. Why does that matter? Any kind of fraud or criminal theft is grounds for a casualty loss. The IRS doesn't care what kind of crime it was.

Comment: Your stock was *stolen* from you (as in you used to own shares in Company A, and you no longer do, because some other person now holds those shares and/or illegitimately sold them without your consent, or similar), or you have stock that is valueless due to bankruptcy?  I'm not entirely sure I understand the details of the question at this point.

Comment: @FiveBagger, Re: Embezzlement by an insider; wouldn't this loss then be captured by the organization, not by the shareholders of the organization?

Comment: @quid If the organization owes him shares that they don't hold, that's different than him having equity in an organization that had embezzlement occur.

Comment: @NathanL, I agree, but I'm not sure I understand the relationship to the holding company that filed bankruptcy because of the embezzlement which seems to be vital to the issue.  If a securities broker filed bankruptcy wouldn't SIPC get involved?

Comment: The confusion could be cleared up if the OP would provide the name of the stock and the name of the holding company, and identify which one experienced fraud, and which one went bankrupt.

Comment: Until/unless OP clarifies what is actually happening here, this should be closed as "unclear" as it's not possible to answer this (Especially with it being on HNQ).

Comment: If you wanted to claim the $300,000 loss (your $250,000 is wrong) you would also have to claim a $250,000 gain.  Even if there was a way to go down the road you're trying to go it wouldn't do you any good.

Comment: Now that there are more details, were you unable to make a claim to SIPC for the securities?

Answer (score 9):

You are not the person or entity against whom the crime was committed, so the Casualty Loss (theft) deduction doesn't apply here. You should report this as a Capital Loss, the same way all of the Enron shareholders did in their 2001 tax returns. Your cost basis is whatever you originally paid for the shares. The final value is presumably zero. You can declare a maximum capital loss of $3000, so if your net capital loss for the year is greater than that, you'll have to carry over the remainder to the following years.

[IRS publication 547](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p547/ar02.html#en_US_2016_publink1000225208) states:

> **Decline in market value of stock.**   You can't deduct as a theft loss the decline in market value of stock acquired on the open market for investment if the decline is caused by disclosure of accounting fraud or other illegal misconduct by the officers or directors of the corporation that issued the stock. However, you can deduct as a capital loss the loss you sustain when you sell or exchange the stock or the stock becomes completely worthless. You report a capital loss on Schedule D (Form 1040). For more information about stock sales, worthless stock, and capital losses, see chapter 4 of Pub. 550.

Comment: I'm not sure you parsed the question correctly. If another company was holding stock on his behalf, and that company filed bankruptcy proceedings, that's different than him being invested in a company that did the same.

Comment: @NathanL: That's possible. I parsed it as, "I owned stock in ENE, and ENE went bankrupt due to fraud." You're suggesting that the case might be "I owned stock in GOOG that was held by Fly-By-Night-Brokerage-R-Us, and Fly-By-Night-Brokerage-R-Us went bankrupt due to fraud." OP can clarify, but the first is the more common case.

Comment: I'm sure the first is more common, but I can't imagine a scenario where that happened AND the stock doubled while the issue was winding its way through the courts.

Comment: I think Nathan's right - "I have a stock that was held by ..." suggests that this is equivalent to Vanguard going bankrupt due to fraud, or some such.  I'm not sure it invalidates this answer - but I think this answer is premature, and most _likely_ making an incorrect assumption.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. In my case the assets were STOLEN. The stock I had was not in the company that went bankrupt. They STOLE my stock which they were holding as a trustee by secretely selling it and embezzling the money. This is not a case of me having stock in company that went bankrupt. You are misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @FiveBagger Thanks for clarifying. In that case, this answer IS incorrect because it makes an incorrect assumption. Should I delete it, leave it to be voted down, or change it to be correct?

Comment: @FiveBagger: you should update your question to clarify that aspect, as it isn't clear in what you have written.